# Laravel + passport: Facing issue 401 Unauthorised

Tags: php, laravel, passport.js, shared-hosting

I have created a Laravel Application and included passport for authentication. The application is working fine on my local system.

But when I have deployed the application on the shared hosting platform I am facing issue where I am getting error 401 Unauthorised on the request I am passing to the server.

Though, the login API is working fine and generating access token. I am facing difficulty to find out the reason for it.

Could anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Attaching image the way I am sending the request:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you send access_token in your headers like this:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'Authorization': "Bearer your_access_token",
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes I did that. Still facing issue.

Comment: Please can you check it from network in you developer tools to see if it included correctly in `headers`

Comment: I am using postman, so yeah its included. Moreover if I am using same request on my local it's working fine.

Comment: Okay no problem, but where you save your access_token after login?

Comment: In the database. And I am not doing that. Its passport who is doing it.

Comment: So you don't understand how it works.
Can you send just how you send token with ajax request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197090/discussion-between-tavish-aggarwal-and-mohammed-aktaa).

Comment: did you solve this issue @TavishAggarwal ? i also facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$ 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it